# Why one statement calls copy constructor while the other one call calls copy-assignment operator?

Tags: c++

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


class numbered{
    public:
        int value;
        numbered(){}
        numbered& operator= (const numbered& n){
            this->value=n.value+1;
            return *this;
        }
        numbered (const numbered& n){
            this->value=n.value+2;
        }
};


int main(void){
    numbered n1;
    n1.value=15;
    numbered n2=n1;
    numbered n3;
    n3=n1;
    cout << n2.value <<endl;
    cout << n3.value <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Above this code segment, why does `numbered n2=n1` call copy constructor while `numbered3 n3;n3=n1;` calls copy-assignment operator. Both of two variables, n2 and n3, are assigned by `=`. So what is the difference between two of them?

Comment: `numbered n2=n1;` is initiailzation while `n3=n1;` is assignment.

Comment: @Anoop Rana Is that mean copy constructor works in initialization while copy-assignment operator works in assignment expression?

Comment: Basically yes as explained in my answer below. More details can be found at the links given in my answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: "Both of two variables, n2 and n3, are assigned by =. " No, they aren't. Just because the code says `=`, doesn't mean it's an assignment.

Comment: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Statement 1

When you wrote:

```
numbered n2 = n1; //this is initialization and so this uses copy constructor
```

The above statement is **initialization** of variable `n2` using variable `n1`. And from [copy constructor's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor):

> The copy constructor is called whenever an object is **initialized** (by direct-initialization or copy-initialization) from another object of the same type...

Since in this case we are doing initialization so according to the above quoted statement, this will use copy constructor.

##### Statement 2

On the other hand, when you wrote:

```
n3=n1; //this is assignment expression and so this uses copy assignment operator
```

The above statement is an **assignment** of `n1` to `n3`. And from [copy assignment operator's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment):

> The copy assignment operator is called whenever selected by overload resolution, e.g. **when an object appears on the left side of an assignment** expression.

Since the object `n3` appears on the left side of the assignment expression, therefore according to the quoted statement above, this uses copy assignment operator.